# jQuery why don't I get any output in the console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to have some variable values change on `window.resize()` and add them to a global variable.

When I try to output the variable `section1` I dont´t get any output in the console and I don´t understand why. It would be very nice if somebody can help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var section1, section2, section3;

    $(window).resize(function(){
            windowHeight = $(window).height();
            section1 = windowHeight;
            section2 = windowHeight * 2;
            section3 = windowHeight * 3;
            log();
    });

    function log() {
      console.log(section1);
    }
  }
```

Comment: "No output" ... as in the `console.log()` is never executed?

Comment: Is it a typo that you're missing an ending `)`? With this fix, it works fine [in a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3gvagxx4/)